# MySQL write a trigger to prevent from buying too much

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table `warehouse` where I have information about articles in my store (article id as foreign key and quantity). Then, I have another table, `shoppinglist` where I have a clients id, article id and quantity. Lets say, that client wants to buy 3 articles but theres only one article available. How to write a `trigger` which help me to prevent from buying too much?

I tried this:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER check BEFORE INSERT ON shoppinglist FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF warehouse.quantity < shoppinglist.quantity THEN CALL fail('You cant buy that much'); END IF; END $$ DELIMITER;
```

but this seems not to work. I mean, when I do:

```
INSERT INTO shoppinlist (clients_id, article_id, quantity) VALUES (1, 2, 100);
```

having only 2 articles with id = 2 on warehouse its ok, its possible. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error when you create the trigger?  If you do `show triggers`, does it look right?

Answer (score 1):

What specific article would warehouse.quantity or shoppingList.quantity refer to in your code?
Also, `check` is a reserved keyword.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER qtyCheck BEFORE INSERT ON shoppinglist 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  SET @qty = (SELECT quantity FROM warehouse WHERE article_id = NEW.article_id);
  IF @qty < NEW.quantity THEN
    CALL fail('You cant buy that much'); 
  END IF; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that I renamed the trigger, I'm guessing the name of the `article_id` column on the `warehouse` table, I used the `NEW` variable instead of `shoppingList` within the body of the trigger, and you need a space before the semicolon in `DELIMITER ;`, though this might've been a typo when posting.

Finally, you may get the following error if the `fail` function isn't defined. It doesn't exist on my system...

```
ERROR 1305: PROCEDURE testing.fail does not exist
```